# jdbc why isn't javax.sql.PooledConnection inherited from java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Every time we implement a PooledConnection we write

```
class MyConnection implements PooledConnection, Connection {
  // implement methods of PooledConnection and Connection 
}
```

And I am wondering why `PooledConnection` was not designed as `extends Connection`? since a `PooledConnection` is always a `Connection` after all.

Comment: Experience shows that functionality should be specified as interfaces, not by extending classes.  Just look at `Properties` as a good example of why not (Properties are not HashMaps)

Comment: I'm not sure how that follows; neither `Connection` nor `PooledConnection` are classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm by no means sure, but I imagine the reason `PooledConnection` doesn't extend `Connection` is so that you can make a significantly simpler `PooledConnection` implementation that uses any other existing `Connection` implementation, allowing code-reuse and keeping functionality separate.

Comment: Suppose we have an implementation for `Connection` called `ConnectionImpl` we can still write: `class MyConnection extends ConnectionImpl implements PooledConnection`, right?

Comment: You could. But I believe the point would be that you wouldn't need to if you let `MyConnection` only implement `PooledConnection`, and then return instances of `ConnectionImpl` in the `getConnection()` method.

Comment: Because you can write a single PooledConnection class for many different connection object types should you choose.  It allows you to write wrap an existing connection into a PooledConnection object.  If this weren't the case it would be a pain to write external libraries to do the pooling, since you'd have to override every single connection method to wrap one and delegate to another instance.

Comment: Oh. The mention of PooledConnection.getConnection method makes sense. And the javadoc of PooledConnection gives useful information.

Answer (score 2):

> ... since a PooledConnection is always a Connection after all.

Actually, that's the whole point.  The `PooledConnection` interface design *allows* the `PooledConnection` instance to be a *distinct* object from the `Connection` instance.

Why would you do that?  Well in an XA implementation, there are potentially many different implementations of `Connection` from different database vendors, and the `PooledConnection` classes are designed to deal with "stuff" over the top of that; e.g. coordination of transactions across multiple databases.  Keeping the two interfaces distinct means that the XA implementation doesn't need to implement XA-level connections as wrapper objects.

And of course, since `PooledConnection` and `Connection` *interfaces*, they can be implemented by the same connection class ... if the situation requires it.

(Or at least, that is my theory.  To get a definitive answer, you'd need to ask the people who wrote the specification(s) that gave rise to those interfaces.)

Answer (score 1):

A `PooledConnection` is a **handle** to a physical connection. This physical connection object might be a a JDBC `Connection`, but on the other hand it could just as well be a lower-level database-specific construct.

The handle is what a connection pool uses to create logical `Connection`-objects to hand out to clients of the connection pool (using the `getConnection()` method. When the client closes that connection, the connection pool is notified that the `PooledConnection` is available again.

A `PooledConnection` is not intended to be used directly as a `Connection`, so it does not extend the Connection interface.